# Python code behaving differently depending on whether I pass a list directly into the constructor, or as a variable

Tags: python

I'm writing a simple bullet hell game using pygame. There is a point on the screen which I chose as an origin for my bullets. Originally, I passed the origin point to the constructor as a two element list directly, which works just [fine](https://gyazo.com/93bc900d059dc7a6db09038fd22ccd3d). When I tried to assign the exact same list to the variable, and pass the variable to the constructor [this](https://gyazo.com/dd3ccc52d0885cbf131e3bbc02f14410) happenes.

That's how I defined the class representing bullets:

```
class Bullet():
    def __init__(self, pos, angle, birth, speed_mod, bullet_skin):
        self.pos = pos
        self.dir = Angle(angle)
        self.angle = angle
        self.birth = birth
        self.image = bullet_skin
        self.rotated = 0
        self.speed_mod = speed_mod
    def draw(self):
        a = self.get_pos()
        x = a[0]
        y = a[1]
        if not self.rotated:
            self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, -self.angle + 90)
            self.rotated = 1
        screen.blit(self.image, (x - 10, y - 10))

    def move(self, speed_mod):
        self.pos[0] += speed_mod * bullet.dir[0]
        self.pos[1] += speed_mod * bullet.dir[1]

    def get_pos(self):
        return [round(self.pos[0]), round(self.pos[1])]

    def on_screen(pos):
        return pos[0] > 0 and pos[0] < 800 and pos[1] > 10 and pos[1] < 600

    def is_dead(self):
        return pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.birth > 3000 or not Bullet.on_screen(self.get_pos())
```

That's how I defined class spawning bullets:

```
origin = [400, 20]
class Spawn():
    global origin
    def __init__(self, delay, state, offset):
        self.delay = delay
        self.state = state
        self.offset = offset
    def wave(self, Bullets): #the code works fine if you replace the origin with [400, 20] list here
        for x in range(36):
            Bullets.append(Bullet(origin, 10 * x + self.offset, pygame.time.get_ticks(), 5, blue_bullet))
    def single(self, Bullets):
        Bullets.append(Bullet([400, 20], randint(60, 120), pygame.time.get_ticks(), 3, purple_bullet))
    def bomb(self, Bullets):
        for x in range(18):
            Bullets.append(Bullet([100, 100], 20 * x + self.offset, pygame.time.get_ticks(), 6, red_bullet))
```

My whole code can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/Bbf4meDs)

Comment: TitleCased names are reserved for class names in Python, swap `Bullets` for `bullets` in your methods.

Comment: You're passing one global list to every Bullet, so they are all sharing the same list for their `pos`. When that list is altered, all bullets affected.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that you create a single list pointed by the variables `origin`. Then that list gets passed to every bullet you create without making a copy. When you modify the position of a bullet you are mutating that list and thus a different starting point is being used for the bullets. The easiest fix is to make a copy of the list:

```py
Bullet(origin[:], 10 * x + self.offset, pygame.time.get_ticks(), 5, blue_bullet)
```

To see what is happening you can run the following example:

```py
a = [0, 1, 2]
b = a
c = a[:]

c.append(3)
print(a, b, c)
b.append(4)
print(a, b, c)
```

Which of the operations affected `a`?

Answer (score 0):

`origin` is a global list that you are passing to every new instance of Bullet.

Each Bullet instance stores a reference to this list as its `pos`. So they are all sharing one `pos`. When the list is altered, every Bullet is affected.

Possible fixes:

- Pass `origin[:]` (a copy of the list) instead of `origin` to each bullet.
- Have Bullet's `__init__` method copy `origin` when it receives it.
- Consider using an immutable type, like a tuple, for a constant like `origin`, to avoid mutation errors like this. You can reassign the `pos` instead of mutating it; or you can convert it to a list as Bullet receives it, if that's the way you prefer.